# Removing items from a list in a request.session is not working I do not understand why

Tags: django, session, django-views, django-forms

I try to create a basic Q&A game. In the request.session['questions'] I am saving the questions I want to render .

The flow should be :

Question 1 as son the form is loaded --> once the user click next  question 2 shoul be rendered an so on until the request.session['questions']  is empty.

whit the following code I Only could show the 2 first options and I don`t know why is not working as expected.

```
def game(request): 
    
    
    if request.method == 'GET':
        request.session['questions'] = ['question1','question2','question3','question4'] 
        print(request.session['questions'])    
        q = request.session['questions'].pop(0)
        form = QForm({'question':q})
        print(request.session['questions'])
        return render(request, 'game.html', {'form':form})
        
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST' and len(request.session['questions']) >0:
            q= request.session['questions'].pop(0)
            print(name)
            form = QForm({'question':q})            
            return render(request, 'game.html', {'form':form})          
        
        else:
            return redirect('home')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

views.py

```
def game(request):
    questions = ['question1','question2','question3','question4']

    if request.method == 'POST':
        answer = request.POST['answer']
        questions = request.POST['questions']
        
        q_list = questions[1:-1].replace('\'', '').split(',')
        q_list.pop(0)
        if q_list:
            questions = q_list
        else:
            questions = None

    context = { 'questions': questions }
    return render(request, 'game.html', context)
```

game.html template:

```
{% if questions %}
    <form action="{% url 'your:url' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="question">{{questions.0}}</label>
        <input 
            id="answer" 
            type="text" 
            name="answer" 
            placeholder="Enter your answer..."
        >
        <input type="hidden" name="questions" value="{{questions}}">
        <input type="submit" value="OK">
    </form>
{% else %}
    Game Over
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks Niko, is not exactly what I needed but it helps me to understand.